# Data insertion fails for bigquery using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using bigquery client by tyler treat (https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) through python, the code compiles without error and returns true for table exists, but data insertion fails. Please let me know if something is wrong in the following code.

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from bigquery import get_client
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import sys, os

json_key = 'key.json'
client = get_client(json_key_file=json_key, readonly=True)
exists = client.check_table('Ucare', 'try')
schema = [
            {'name' : 'time', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'}]
created = client.create_table('Ucare', 'try', schema)
print created
print exists
rows = [('time':'ipvbs6k16sp6bkut')]
#rows = { 'rows':[{'json':{'event_type':'_session.stop'},'insertId' : 0}]}
inserted = client.push_rows('Ucare', 'try', rows,'24556135')
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you mean by fails? Do you get an error? Does the data not show up in the table?

Comment: The json format was wrong in the above program, that's why i was receiving an error in runtime. I have corrected it now.